# Installing the package ZIGP from R archive

Tags: r, file, installation, local, package

I'm unable to install the ZIGP package in **R (version 2.14.1)**. I've downloaded the file ZIGP_3.8.tar.gz from http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ZIGP/ to the directory
`"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\library"`. I've already tried several ways to install this package, but without success! For instance, I entered into the R program as an administrator (item "Run as administrator") and I've tried the command
`install.packages("ZIGP", pkgs="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.1/library/ZIGP_3.8.tar.gz",repos=NULL)`, and the error message was:

```
Warning in install.packages("ZIGP", pkgs = "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.1/library/ZIGP_3.8.tar.gz",  :
  'lib = "ZIGP"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("ZIGP", pkgs = "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.1/library/ZIGP_3.8.tar.gz",  : 
  unable to install packages
```

I've changed the security status in R properties, but the error remains the same.

Do anyone have any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks very much in advance.